# Why my activity is not shown the same way when the app is running than in my .xml file

Tags: android, xml

Here´s my problem. I have a login activity in android. Here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary_color"
    tools:context=".activities.LoginActivity">

    <!--<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextEmail"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:textColorHint="@color/primary_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="37dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextUsername"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextId"
        tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />-->


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
        android:layout_width="202dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Contraseña"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:text=""
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:textColorHint="@color/primary_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonLogin"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextId"
        android:layout_width="191dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="ID"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text=""
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:textColorHint="@color/primary_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextUsername"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.022" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextUsername"
        android:layout_width="221dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Nombre de usuario"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:textColorHint="@color/primary_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextPassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
        android:layout_width="152dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="#23F62B"
        android:text="Entrar"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The problem is that when I run the app, it is not shown the same way. Look at the following photo to see the difference:
[image]

On the left it is like I want it to be, but on the right it is when the app is running and I don´t know why that happens.
Any idea?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Don't provide harcoded width just use match_parent instead

For example:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Contraseña"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:text=""
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:textColorHint="@color/primary_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonLogin"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score -1):

The configuration between your IDE and your emulator might be different. You use a Custom device as reference in your IDE on API 33, maybe your device does not have the same configuration leading to differencies.

Comment: Using compose isn't a magic wand that will fix anything here.

Comment: @GabeSechan What about the configuration i'm talking?

Comment: Could be.  Really, the preview tool is only so-so in accuracy.  I don't even use it.  I test on device/emulator, and I've learned how to read XML and know how it's displayed.  Relying on the preview is risky.  His code itself is kind of iffy at best-  lots of harcoded sizes, which is generally a bad idea.  It looks like he dragged and dropped without knowing what it did, and that's not a good way to make UIs on Android